# Integrating Sygic or Copilot in PhoneGap App

Tags: sygic

I'd like to know whether it is possible to integrate the GPS navigation using either Sygic or Copilot in a PhoneGap/Apache Cordova application?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. If you want to know more about how thats a different question and have different solutions based on intent, geo url etc.